# Background image repeats despite setting to "Clip"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, rdl

I am trying to show a "check" or "X" image inside a tablix cell based on a Condition. I have added both Images to the image Folder and am setting the BackGroundImage Value property to this expression...

```
=IIF(Fields!PASS.Value = 1,"CheckMark","XMark")
```

I've also set Background Repeat to Clip. Inside Preview view it looks fine, but when pushing the rdl to the server and running the report locally, the image continues to repeat to fill the textbox. 
I am running IE8 and SSRS 2008. Is there a better approach in doing this without setting Background Image property, realistically I'd like to just set the TextBox value property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative would be to use the show/hide parameter in the text box to control which of the images gets hidden.  I'm not sure if this would solve your not repeating option, but it is something you can try.  You would set both images to show in each box and write a conditional formula (the inverse of your formula above, pretty much) to hide an image based on value.  I'm not sure if that would mess up the alignment for you though, unless you can place the two images on top of eachother since only 1 should show anyway.

It seems that you are not alone with this issue, as there are several other posts about it going back as far as 2010 when I google it.  The last status I saw was that it was submitted as a bug to Microsoft, and it seems all of the users had to find workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I changed my approach a bit for how I rendered images. I inserted a rectangle on the page, and then drag and dropped the image inside the rectangle. This allowed me to "change" the background color as well, because these items were inside an alternating color tablix grid. Putting the image inside the rectangle seemed like the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I was only getting the repeating Background image 'feature' despite having BackgroundRepeat set to 'Clip' when using an image encoded in a database field or where the name of the embeded image was coming from the database i.e. where Value was set to an Expression.

What I found worked was to set BackgroundRepeat to the Expression **="Clip"**.

Note that I'm working in 2013/2014 RDL/RDLC but it seems to be the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  I found by setting the MIMEtype and setting BackgroundRepeat to Clip fixed the issue.